# Is it possible to create a function to insert an object into a queue? Using java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java

So I have created a menu choice display where I have the function `insert()`
Now, I am trying to use a `Scanner` to input an object(Person) into the queue.
So my code is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter element: ");
Person elementInsert = input.next();
```

But obviously this does not work, `Scanner` seems to only accept integers and `String`. Is there a way to do this? I'm not sure if my question is clear.
But I am trying to insert an object into a data structure(Queue) using the `java.util.Scanner`
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is a `Person`?

Comment: So the problem that you have is not with inserting into a queue, but how do you accept a complex object. Right?

If that's the case, please add some detailon what a "Person" is. Is it a JSON? Is it an XML? Is it an Image? Is it a binary object?

Comment: Person is a class which contains attribute such as name, disease, age etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `static` method in the Person class that knows how to build a person from the input. Here is a complete example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public static Person createFromInput(Scanner input) {
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            return new Person(firstName, lastName);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person {" + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter element: ");
        Person person = Person.createFromInput(input);

        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

You should probably add some validation in order to make sure the code is reading a valid Person. Ideally you should have unit tests that cover all cases.

Comment: This approach is better than trying to override a constructor; essentially a static factory approach.

Comment: By the way if you're trying to **store** objects or share them between different applications, maybe have a look at the Java Serialization API: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter element: ");
    Person elementInsert = new Person(input.next());
```

This will require your Person class to have a constructor that uses your input accordingly. Then assuming your Queue has been defined already, you can do something like:

```
    queue.add(elementInsert);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know Scanner is a utility given by Java developer. You can't use it for getting any object from user. Rather you can define you own method for doing this.

```
public Person getPerson(){
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  //write code for getting attributes for person
  Person p = new Person(arg1,arg2);
}

Person p = getPerson();
queque.add(p);
```